# Adding a TextView inside a PreferenceScreen's Preference

Tags: android, android-layout

In this preferenceScreen the user unlinks the device from his account. At the moment I just have it as Unlink device, once the user clicks it, the unlinking happens.

But I would like to add a piece text like this:

Joe Foo's Device (joefoo@gmail.com) - Unlink Device

Hoe would I do this? I also need to add the user name dynamically from settingsActivity.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <Preference android:title="@string/pref_title_advanced_unlink" >
         <TextView somehow must be in here
            android:id="@id/user_name_and_email" />

         <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.tvrplayer"
            android:targetClass="com.example.tvrplayer.UnlinkActivity" 
            android.setflags="FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP"/>
    </Preference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences have a subtitle called `summary`. Give your preference a key, then you can use `findPreference(CharSequence key)` in your PreferenceFragment to get a reference to your preference object, sort of like calling `findViewById` to get references to Views. Then call `setSummary(int)` or `setSummary(CharSequence)` on the preference object.

Alternatively, you could do something entirely more complex by providing a custom layout for your preference objects and/or subclass `Preference` and implement some custom data binding. But I think the above should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, the first option was simple as pie! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="pref_title_advanced"
        android:title="Advanced" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="pref_title_advanced_link"
            android:title="Link Device" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**PrefsActivity.java**

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mPrefListener;
private CheckBoxPreference mCheckBoxPref;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    mCheckBoxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
            "pref_title_advanced_link");
    /*
     * set initial summary as you desire. For example, userIdCurrent can be:
     * "No Devices linked."
     */
    mCheckBoxPref.setSummary(userIdCurrent);

    mPrefListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
                String key) {
            if (key.equals("pref_title_advanced_link")) {
                /*
                 * set post-click summary as you desire. For example,
                 * userIdPost can be:
                 * "Joe Foo's Device (joefoo@gmail.com)".
                 */
                mCheckBoxPref.setSummary(userIdPost);
            }
        }
    };
    mPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPrefListener);
}
```